How to edit CPPFLAGS in Crosstool-NG?
I'm new to using crosstool-ng and want to build the compiler with specific C++ symbols enabled.
I enabled C++ under ct-ng's menuconfig, in C compiler -> C++. However, I don't see anywhere to modify the CPPFLAGS environment variable for building the compiler. I only see the option to edit CFLAGS.
Is there some setting I am missing? I haven't seen this issue anywhere else.
